# Link bug on the iPad app

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, ios-app

If you try and insert a link, and try to add an optional title, you do not have a space bar button to use. You also do not have quotation marks.

I am using the beta app on an iPad running iOS 8.1.3.

Note: other people can reproduce this, so it isn't just me.

Screenshot:

[image: image of no space bar]

Comment: Whoneedsaspacebar?

Comment: @Doorknob You can't add the optional title without the space bar.

Comment: Yes, I know. It was a joke. (Evidently a bad one.) :)

Comment: I'm glad you brought this up. I have a lot of issues with the iOS app, so I rarely use it, however, I just tried to reproduce your concern and the exact same thing happened to me. Please add me to those requesting a fix for this! Thanks!

Comment: @Sue I mentioned that. Thank you!

Comment: @Sue I'd love to hear more about your issues.

Comment: @BrianNickel I'd consider it an honor to discuss the app with you! Do you hang out in the Tavern, or the chat site on Ask Different, or do you want me to express my concerns here?

Comment: @Sue Sure, I can hang out in the Tavern or we have our own [seldom use room for the iOS app](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/705/ios-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be switching to a standard keyboard in the next build.  Let's see if there are any complaints about that.  (I wouldn't expect anyone to ever type out a URL but you never know.)

Comment: Yes! It works! But the description becomes part of the link, and not the actual [ ] part.

Comment: @awesomebing1 That's the intended behavior, matching the web UI. http://i.stack.imgur.com/JBKBI.png  The optional title is text that appears when a mouse pointer hovers over it. http://i.stack.imgur.com/2FsYA.png It doesn't make as much sense on device I guess as you never see title text.